# ajax GET request with JSON body in browser

Tags: html, json, ajax, get, xmlhttprequest

I know, I know, this sounds dumb, but I'm talking to a REST API, and I need to send a GET request with a JSON body.  This is how the API was written, and I don't have a choice.

I've written my own C# code which accomplishes this using HTTP sockets, but now I'm trying to do it in the browser, and not having a lot of luck.  I need to do this in plan JavaScript/JQuery, so I can't use Angular, or similar.

Taken from the horses mouth [MSDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send)

> If the request method is GET or HEAD, the body parameter is ignored
>   and the request body is set to null.

Is there anyway of doing this in the browser, using JQuery or similar?

Comment: @Pourbahrami — What makes you think Axios can achieve it (given it is just a wrapper around XMLHttpRequest … which the quoted documentation says won't do it)

Comment: Just took a look at axio 'Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', and 'PATCH'', but thanks anyway